Adding bottom navigation to fragment - navHostFragment returns null
I am trying to add bottom navigation to a fragment but it is not working as I get the following error at run time
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                              
Process: com.otemainc.m_kliniki, PID: 29940                                                                                                 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.otemainc.m_kliniki/com.otemainc.m_kliniki.controller.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment                                                                                                     
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2993)                                                                                                        
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)                                                                                                     
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)                                                                                                      
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)                                                                                                      
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)                                                                                                        
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1888)                                                                                                      
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)                                                                                                      
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)                                                                                                       
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6801)                                                                                                         
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                        
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:518)                                                                                                         
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)                                                                                                   
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment                                                                                                    
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                                                        
at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)                                                                                                        
at com.otemainc.m_kliniki.controller.fragments.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:33)                                                                                                       
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3114)                                                                                                      
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:557)                                                                                                      
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)                                                                                                         
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:114)                                                                                                       
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1455)                                                                                                      
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3034)                                                                                                      
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2945)                                                                                                      
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3148)                                                                                                         
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:410)                                                                                                      
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:271)                                                                                                     
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)                                                                                                      
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:136)                                                                                                        
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:247)                                                                                                       
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:226)                                                                                                        
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)                                                                                                        
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)                                                                                                        
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)                                                                                                         
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)                                                                                                         
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:995)                                                                                                         
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:859)                                                                                                         
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)                                                                                                         
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:995)                                                                                                         
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:859)                                                                                                         
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)                                                                                                         
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)                                                                                                      
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)                                                                                                      
at com.otemainc.m_kliniki.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:53)                                                                                                       
at com.otemainc.m_kliniki.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:47)                                                                                                       
at com.otemainc.m_kliniki.controller.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
2024-10-23 08:06:51.946 29940-29940 AndroidRuntime          com.otemainc.m_kliniki               E      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7185)                                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7176)                                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1285)                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2973)                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)                                                                                                     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)                                                                                                     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1888)                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6801)                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:518)                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Basically, what I have done is to add bottom navigation and Fragment container view that will act as the host fragment as follows
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context=".controller.fragments.HomeFragment">
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_nav"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
    />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

I have also created the nav graph and named each navigation fragment item id with the same name as in the menu items as follows
//The navigation fragment
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph.xml"
app:startDestination="@id/userDashboardFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/userDashboardFragment"
    android:name="com.otemainc.m_kliniki.controller.fragments.UserDashboardFragment"
    android:label="fragment_user_dashboard"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_user_dashboard" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/calculatorFragment"
    android:name="com.otemainc.m_kliniki.controller.fragments.CalculatorFragment"
    android:label="fragment_calculator"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_calculator" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/reservationFragment"
    android:name="com.otemainc.m_kliniki.controller.fragments.ReservationFragment"
    android:label="fragment_reservation"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_reservation" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/walletFragment"
    android:name="com.otemainc.m_kliniki.controller.fragments.WalletFragment"
    android:label="fragment_wallet"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_wallet" />
    </navigation>

  //The menu

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/userDashboardFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/baseline_home_filled"
    android:title="@string/menu_home" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/calculatorFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/sigma"
    android:title="@string/calculator" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/reservationFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/baseline_calendar_today"
    android:title="@string/reservations"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/walletFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/baseline_person_outline"
    android:title="@string/wallet" />
 </menu>

Finally in my HomeFragment.java file, I've added the code to initialize each item and setup the navigation controller as follows
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    BottomNavigationView navigationView = root.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.userDashboardFragment, R.id.calculatorFragment, R.id.reservationFragment, R.id.walletFragment)
            .build();
    AppCompatActivity appCompat = (AppCompatActivity) requireActivity();
    NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) appCompat.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_nav);
    NavController navController = Objects.requireNonNull(navHostFragment).getNavController();
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController((AppCompatActivity) this.requireActivity(), navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    return root;
}

The code crushes when run despite not showing any errors on the IDE and when I set debug points, I realize that the issue is with navHostFragment being null. What could I be missing, Any ideas on how to set the navhostfragment to the one in fragment_home.xml successfully?
After setting debug points at the crushing line and the one above it, the following are screenshots of the outputs



Please reformat your error message and include the entire error message (you've cut it off too early).

@ianhanniballake I have added the full error message and screenshots of the two debug points I set showing the null navHostFragment

The layout of the default NavHostFragment should be the activity layout, not the main fragment layout

Your stack trace is one consistent with using the <fragment> tag (which you should not be using in any layout), instead of the FragmentContainerView your layout XML you've included here says you are using. Are you sure that is the right XML?

R.layout.fragment_home might not have any of these elements ...this layout with the FragmentContainerView should rather be inflated as the ActivityMainBinding.

@ianhanniballake yes it is. I have tried using fragment in place of FragmentContainerView but the error is still the same

Try <fragment instead of  <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView

It should be android:id="@+id/nav_graph" not android:id="@+id/nav_graph.xml"

Ihave tried changing to that but the error persists

@TheOnlySmartBoy Can you share a sample project where the issue is reproducible?

@user2784462 Basically what I am trying to achieve is have both bottom navigation and navigation drawer in the same activity. So far I have been able to add the navigation drawer and I wanted to add the bottom navigation to the FragmentHome as I have explained above but I get the error when running

@TheOnlySmartBoy What i mean is that create a sample project where the issue is reproducible and share the project file here
